# handleOpenURL for a deep link is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, deep-linking

Basically I'm trying to open an app with a deeplink and also, after executing some functions, turn back to app1. I'm using cordova and ionic.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

but handleOpenURL is never called.

The code is the next:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <title>BEM Móvil</title>
  <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest">
  <link href="lib/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ng-idle/angular-idle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ng-pattern-restrict/src/ng-pattern-restrict.min.js"></script>

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.js"></script>
  <script src="app/security/security.js"></script>
  <script src="app/mitm/mitm.js"></script>

  <!-- 
  ***************************
  ***************************
  ******* CONTROLLERS *******
  ***************************
  ***************************
-->

<script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>


  <!-- 
  ************************
  ************************
  ******* SERVICES *******
  ************************
  ************************-->

<script src="js/services/securityService.js"></script>


<script src="mfp-scripts/init.js"></script>

 <script>
        handleOpenURL = function (url) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.foo = 'The url is ' + url;
            },0);
        };
    </script>

</head>
```

When the application is opened how can I tell to a controller that the app was opened by an url?